# How to display certain part of one web-site at Facebook iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe

I need to display in  Facebook iframe a certain part of http://usatoday.com web-site. Only this part 
http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/5497/4141414.png

Is it possible? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Just create new html(php) page and put there only content you need ...